# changing the height of a div using javascript dynamically does not works

Tags: javascript, html

I have two div's.The height of first div changes with the height of second div.But code seems to have some trouble.My code is below.
For example,

```
<div id="profile1">akdsfkj</div>

<div id="schedules1" style="min-height:150px;"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('profile1').style.height=$('#schedules1').height();
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: $.height() returns an integer, while setting style.height needs a string with a measure unit, eg. "20px"; so try adding +"px" before semicolon.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas: That's an *answer*, not a comment.

Comment: @Crowder:Sorry,I tried more scripts and accidently fed into this unusal mixing of DOM and js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `height` property on the DOM `style` object requires units, but jQuery's `height()` method just returns a number (of pixels). So:

```
document.getElementById('profile1').style.height=$('#schedules1').height() + "px";
// Change ----------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

<s>But note that the `style` attribute on your `schedules1` element is invalid, you've used `min:height:150px` rather than `min-height:150px`.</s> *(It's fixed in the question now.)*

Also, it's a bit odd to mix jQuery and straight DOM code in this way. Using all jQuery:

```
$('#profile1').css("height", $('#schedules1').height());
```

Comment: Also `$('#profile1').height($('#schedules1').height());` should work.

Comment: @Nenotlep: Thanks. For some reason, I keep forgetting that `height` can also be a setter.

Answer (score 0):

By using Jquery we can do this..

```
var fheight=$('#profile1').height();
$('#schedules1').css('height',fheight);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fCDV/)):

HTML (change `min:height` to `min-height`):

```
<div id="profile1">akdsfkj</div>
<div id="schedules1" style="min-height:150px;"></div>
```

JavaScript (use jQuery to set the `height`):

```
$('#profile1').height($('#schedules1').height());
```